# Hosting multiple sites with Apache2

Tags: apache2, dns, virtualhost

I have on a server machine a local domain called "localwiki.com" that points to /var/www/wiki and works fine.

The sites-available and sites-enable configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/wiki/
ServerName localwiki.com
ServerAlias *.localwiki.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I wanted to create a second local domain for /var/www/doxygen (which I can access using "serverIP"/doxygen).

Here is the localdoxygen.com config file created at /etc/apache2/sites-available/localdoxygen.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/doxygen/
ServerName localdoxygen.com
ServerAlias *localdoxygen.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I used "a2ensite" in order to create a symbolic link in sites-enable pointing to localdoxygen.com in sites-available:

```
sudo a2ensite localdoxygen.com
```

I also have reloaded the new configuration:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

And restarted apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

But the domain (localdoxygen.com), still doesn't work.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve the problem I had to add an entry to /etc/bind in order to activate the DNS for the domain.

Answer (score 1):

I think those conf files must end in .conf to be loaded: i.e. localdoxygen.com.conf

Answer (score 1):

1. disable the default site - a2dissite default  (!!!)
2. DNS correct
3. check in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled have your sites
4. reload apache2 /etc/init.d/apache2 reload

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a `NameVirtualHost` in your `apache2.conf` to support multiple domains under one IP.

```
NameVirtualHost 123.456.789.123:80
```

or

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

see also [Running several name-based web sites on a single IP address](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html).

Comment: The file ports.conf already has a line "NameVirtualHost *:80", if I also add this line into apache2.conf I get this warning when reloading config: [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts and domain is still not working.